# css show hide jump issue

Tags: html, css

I want to implement "show/hide" text using css only. I tried following code in fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/phvt8g5w/

```
.show-hide-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.show-hide-text a {
  order: 2;
}

.show-hide-text p {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 60px; // The Height of 3 rows
}

.show-hide-text p {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3; // 3 Rows of text
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

.show-less {
  display: none;
}

.show-less:target {
  display: block;
}

.show-less:target ~ p {
  display: block;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.show-less:target + a {
  display: none;
}
```

Effects are good. But I faced one problem. If I click "show more" link, it will scroll to bottom of the page. Again I go to the top of the page and click the show less link. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: if you use same function to the page bottom, i mean show less function,i think its will be helped to you :)

Comment: i can't understand ur comment clearly

Comment: @LavanyaAkilan Do check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It scrolls to the position of `.show-less` and is the standard behavior when using `:target`.

You can avoid this by using a *ghost* element at the to of the page, which has the advantage of target any element on the page.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.show-hide-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.show-hide-text a {
  order: 2;
}
.show-hide-text p {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 60px; /* The Height of 3 rows */
}
.show-less {
  display: none;
}
 
#show-more:target ~ .show-hide-text p {
  max-height: 100%;
}
#show-more:target ~ .show-hide-text a.show-less {
  display: block;
}
#show-more:target ~ .show-hide-text a.show-more {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="show-more" class="ghost"></div>

<div class="show-hide-text">
  <a class="show-less" href="#show-less">Show less</a>
  <a class="show-more" href="#show-more">Show more</a>
  <p>
   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>
<p>
   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
  
  <p>
   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
  
  <p>
   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
  <p>
   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified answer . Hope this is what you need ;)

> Just changed the target elements and simplified the css to get the
>   desired result !

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.show-hide-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.show-hide-text a {
  order: 2;
}

.show-hide-text p {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 60px; // The Height of 3 rows
}

.show-hide-text p {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3; // 3 Rows of text
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

.show-less {
  display: none;
}


/* Simplified Css For Show Hide */

#a1:target a.show-less {
  display: block
}

#a1:target a.show-more {
  display: none
}

#a1:target p {
  display: block;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="show-hide-text" id="a1">
  <a class="show-more" href="#a1">Show more</a>
  <a class="show-less" href="#">Show less</a>

  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>
<p>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>

<p>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>

<p>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
<p>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
```